# What can I do to let PyCharm find the source of PySide?

Tags: python, pyside, pycharm

I'm using PySide with PyCharm. When I want to jump to the source of a PySide class of method in editor, it always tell me:

```
Cannot find declaration to go to
```

I checked the dir `python27/Lib/site-packages/PySide`, there are many `.pyc` and `.pyd` files, but few `*.py`. I also download the source package from PySide site, but there are many `.cpp` and `.xml` files there.

How can I find the `.py` sources of PySide and let PyCharm to find them? Or I have to read the docs, which is not that convenient.

Comment: For starters, have you checked the thing whose definition you want go to is in one of the Python files?

Comment: It should be in a `.pyd` file. We have to read documents for such files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding something. `.pyd` files (that file extension is specific to windows, but the principle also applies to `.so` files on Linux and whatever file extension other systems use) are extensions written in C or C++ compiled to native code and put into a dynamically-linked library.

While you *could* look at the source if the project in question is open-source (in the case of PySide, it is), it's not Python (do you know C? C++? Quite a few good Python programmers don't) and littered with boilerplate code that contributes nothing but making the cross-language functionality happen. To make matters worse, in the case of PySide the C++ source code is generated automatically (from a tool called Shiboken, which presumably processes the xml files you've seen). You *could* also look at the source of the Qt functions that are wrapped, but again, this unlikely to buy you much.

So the bottom line is: You'll have to stick with the documentation (or read the original Qt documentation; I found it simple enough to translate to Python when I was using PyQt a while ago). Unless it's absolutely terrible (and the original Qt documentation isn't), it will also answer your question:

1. Sooner and with less effort. No need to make your way through thousands of lines of code just to get a rough idea of what that paramter implies.
2. Better. Things like best practices, deprecation warnings and gotchas aren't always visible from the code alone.
3. More correctly. Can *you* understand the code correctly, especially at first glance? I wouldn't bet *I* could.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks for your kind and patient answer!